# The signup for Databricks trial fails

Tags: try-catch, databricks

When signing up for databricks using https://www.databricks.com/try-databricks#account I consistently fail to log in.
To replicate:

Step 1:
[image: Log in screen]

Step 2: Select Get Started with Community Edition

[image]

Step 3: Click verify

[image]

Step 4: Pick the deer (or whatever animal)

[image]

Step 5: Error - The connection to a verification server was interrupted. Please refresh this page to try again.

[image]

This pops up time and time again.

Comment: I’d contact Databricks directly

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White, thanks. I actually did contact them (but no answer). I solved it however,see my answer below. I made this question to share the knowledge how to fix it. In short; Disable any adblocker plugins.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it concerns third-party product support (rather than how to write code for that product), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/11107541) for more information. You should contact the company for support using their service.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue: You should disable any adblockers or privacy plugins and then it works without any issue.

In my case I had to disable uBlock Origin and Privacy Badger. You can disable the plugins on this website by browsing to https://www.databricks.com/try-databricks by clicking the icons in the top right of your browser and choosing 'Disable for this website.